# Bootstrap modal change content on click

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

In my website I am using a bootstrap modal. What I want is to completely change the modal content. When I click a button that's in the modal, so in this case `<h4><a class="btn btn-default" style="color:#0B610B;"><%= product.product_name %></a></h4>`

Here's what my modal look like : [image]

Here's the code of my modal part :

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal<%= i %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div  class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4  class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabe">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="modal-content-id" class="modal-body">
                <%= i %>
                <div id="hide-modal" class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <% @products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 ">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <div class="image-container">
                                    <img id="menu-image" src="/assets/menu/menu-<%= index+1 %>.jpg" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4 class="pull-right"><%= product.product_price %></h4>
                                    <h4><a class="btn btn-default" style="color:#0B610B;"><%= product.product_name %></a></h4>
                                    <p><%= product.product_description %>.</p>
                                </div>

                                <p>
                                    <span><a id="modaltrigger" class="btn btn-default"  >Add</a></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <% end %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and where's the code that tries to change the content?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $('#id_div_to_modify').html('your content');
});
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked. Thanks!

Comment: good, the results display is included in a <div class = " class_name "> , the idea is at the click change the content of this Div.
to do this : it manages li click on the button to change the content .
- Specify the clique event.
- Delete the old content with jquery :
( ' . Class_name ') . $ Html ( '') ; .
- Add the new content with the same method jquer
$ ( ' . Class_name ') . Html ( ' your content you can master of html or js variable ') .